# Method not found error when using BundleTransformer in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, less, bundling-and-minification

We used bundling of LESS code n MVC3 application and everything worked properly.
In our RegisterBundles() we have code as follows:

```
var bundle = new
Bundle("~/assets/styles/EnhancedLayoutLess")
     .Include("~/assets/styles/enhanced-layout.less");
bundle.Transforms.Add(new CssTransformer());
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(bundle);
```

However after upgrade to MVC4, and latest versions of BundleTransformer:Core (1.6.28), BundleTransfomer:LESS (1.6.26) and Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework (1.1.0) when we try to retrieve the bundle we get the following error:

> Method not found:
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1
>   System.Web.Optimization.BundleResponse.get_Files()'.
>
> [MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.IO.FileInfo>
>   System.Web.Optimization.BundleResponse.get_Files()'.]
>
>   BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Process(BundleContext
>   context, BundleResponse response) +0
>
>   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context,
>   String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles) +198
>   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ProcessRequest(BundleContext context)
>   +269    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +913    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165

Any suggestions what should I check? Or how to get LESS bundling working under MVC4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, on first look it seemed like a different issue, this post had a solution to my problem:
[ASP.NET MVC4 App fails to compile Bootstrap.LESS on production while it works on dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372047/asp-net-mvc4-app-fails-to-compile-bootstrap-less-on-production-while-it-works-on)

The underlying cause in both cases was the same. Apparently in MVC4 bundling uses virtual paths and LESS imports that used to resolve properly now cannot find dependent files.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, and I found the solution :)
This problem is caused by YuiCompressorTransform class (Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Web.Optimization).

Process method contains following code:

```
// Grab all of the content.
        var rawContent = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var fileInfo in response.Files)
        {
            using (var reader = fileInfo.OpenText())
            {
                rawContent.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
```

But fileInfo don't have OpenText method.

I've changed this to code below:

```
using (var stream = fileInfo.VirtualFile.Open())
            {
                var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
                rawContent.Append(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
                streamReader.Close();
            }
```

And everything works fine.
Link to correct class: https://gist.github.com/gr4b4z/8349097

Answer (score 0):

Just the [BundleTransformer.Core 1.6.28](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Core/1.6.28) was incompatible with the Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework 1.1.0. At that moment, it was necessary to use the [BundleTransformer.Core 1.7.12 Beta 1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Core/1.7.12-Beta1) or wait for the release of version [1.7.16](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Core/1.7.16).